# Is there a name for being able to quickly find the relevant code?

Tags: design-patterns, programming-practices, source-code, abstraction, maintainability

I notice that a property of codebases that I like hacking on is that it's quick to find the relevant code for some feature, without knowing much about the code base at all. For example, searching for a label in the GUI, and immediately hitting the code that implements that feature.

This seems to be in direct tension with abstraction layers, where the label is probably buried behind an I18N module, and the business logic is probably further removed in an MVC framework. (It can be mitigated by including GUI labels in comments though, for example.)

It's obviously part of maintainability, but is there a name for this specific, desirable, property?

Comment: Maybe "transparency"?

Comment: "Well-organized"?

Comment: I don't think it's a question of organisation. Highly abstracted designs can be well organised, but not very searchable or easy to read.

Comment: This is a great question.

Comment: I think it's called "using a good IDE." So you can jump from place to place through back-references, not search.

Comment: Interesting point. This never seems to work well for me in dynamic languages like Python and JavaScript.

Comment: "What is the name of this thing" questions are off-topic. These are poor questions for the same reasons that "identify this obscure TV show, film or book by its characters or story" are bad questions: you can't Google them, they aren't practical in any way, they don't help anyone else, and allowing them opens the door for the asking of other types of marginal questions. See Also [Let's Play the Guessing Game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game)

Answer (score 4):

Discoverability or learnability *could* be applied to this concept. But note that making something discoverable might be optimizing it for *first time* users. Look [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/06/usability-vs-discoverability.aspx) for a *related* discussion.

Comment: Yeah, interesting point re: first time users. I think with the enormous amount of code readily available these days, that's a much more important consideration than it used to be. (ie, I have to interact with much more unfamiliar code than I used to.)

Answer (score 3):

Although I do not believe that there is a word specifically for this concept, the ease of use of these codebases can often be attributed to several causes, all of which have terms:

- **Well-documented** - Which includes comments, external documentation, internal parsable documentation (like JavaDocs), and indicative variable names.
- **Well-organized** - Shows design and planning
- **Readable** - Besides resulting from the other two, this can be an intentional design choice of certain programming languages, such as Python, who make it a core "pillar" of their design ideology.